# How to send a http request by JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json, http

I am new bee in Android , so the knowledge regarding android is not so vast, Ok lets come to the point, I need to make a **login** by username and password, for that I have to make http requset by JSON and in return the response will also come in JSON. So can anyone can HELP me please in it. THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this code

```
Button show_data;
JSONObject my_json_obj;
String path,firstname,lastname;
path = "http://192.168.101.123:255/services/services.php?id=9";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpEntity  entity;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlconn;
    my_json_obj = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();
        urlconn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        urlconn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlconn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

my_json_obj.put("sUserName", "test2");
      my_json_obj.put("sPassword", "123456");

writer.write(my_json_obj.toString());
        writer.close();

if(true)
        {
            String temp;
            temp = WebRequestCall(my_json_obj);
            //Log.i("Reply", temp);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is more the other way 'round: you send JSON data over HTTP.

Have a look at `HttpURLConnection` and the `org.json.*` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Volley and/or Retrofit? 
If login is not only operation you need to make they can be of much help.