# how to insert data into server database with user input?

Tags: java, php, android, sql

currently, i retrieve data from database is like that

```
private void getdatafromphp(){
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/video.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
       //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
               //paring data
    try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(jArray.length()-1);
        url=json_data.getString("VideoUrl");
    }catch(JSONException e1){
    }catch(ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with this php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("imammuda");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from Video");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

now i want insert data into database. how to do that?

I had found the sql command which is "insert into table (column1, column2) values ('value1', 'value2')".

This is insert with constant values which is type in php.

What i want is from java there get input from user then copy this input into php 'value1' after that run the php to update the database.

Comment: Try this
[link](http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/04/android-phpmysql-connection/)

Comment: Try this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829449/how-to-send-a-http-request-by-json-in-android/5830138#5830138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you are using Get or Post

i will assume GET

```
$value = $_GET['value']; // this will retrieve the value from the url and save it in a variable

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

// escape the value first
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);


mysql_select_db("imammuda");
$result = mysql_query("insert into Video (value) values ('$value')");

?>
```

learn more about working with the [db here](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641)

**UPDATE**

to know the correct request method you can use this.

```
$req;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $req = $_GET;
}else {
    $req = $_POST;
}
```

now you can use $req as your request variable:

```
$value = $req['value'];
```

Comment: when retrieve from database, i was using POST

Comment: In that case simply replace $_GET with $_POST

Comment: opps, then i was wrong, from my above php code, i also don't know what method am i using? what i want to ask is the method(post/get) is set at where?

Comment: ok i added an update to get the correct method, Those are global variables that are set before your script starts to run, so you can access them from everywhere